# Codeigniter Ajax: E-commerce The Query already working but the displaying the data is the problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm making an e-commerce capstone project. The query is already okay but the problem is with displaying the data. If I choose a different category the current category will be hidden and only the new category will be displayed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3kN.jpg

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-9" style="border:solid 1px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4" id="test3">
            <div class="card" id="test">
              <div class="card-body" id="test2">
                <div class="product-grid">
                  <div class="product-image">
                    <a href="#" class="image" style="background-color:#F3F3F3;">
                      <img class="pic-1" src="https://media.comicbook.com/2020/05/dragon-ball-super-when-will-should-goku-master-ultra-instinct-1219439.jpeg?auto=webp&width=1200&height=628&crop=1200:628,smart" class="d-block w-100" id>
                    </a>
                    <a class="add-to-cart" id="cart" href=""> + </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="title" id="productname"><a href="#">Product Name</a></h3>
                    <div class="price" id="price"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="action-buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger mt-3" id="cart" onclick="addtocart()"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
function searchcategory(category_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/getproducts/" + category_id,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        let row = `<div class="price" id="price">${value.price}</div>`;
        let val = `<h3 class="title" id="productname"><a href="#">${value.product_name}</a></h3> `;
        let test = `<button class="btn btn-danger mt-3" id="cart" onclick="${value.product_id}" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>`;

        $('#price').append(row);
        $('#price').append();
        $('#productname').append(val);
        /* $('#test3').append(val);
        $('#cart').text(test); */
        console.log(test);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi , please can you elaborate more on problem ?

Comment: the query sir for getting the data from the database is okay now sir the problem is to display. when i choose in category the data is display but in list. Example: I choose burger all the burgers will display to the right col-md-4 but it display in LIST style

Comment: it display in `display in LIST style ..` please elaborate and excepted output as well .

Comment: The output sir should be like this (i just copy-paste it from bootstrap so i can show you sir the expected output) https://imgur.com/a/9IXlZiM.. not like this https://imgur.com/a/YsLj9S2

Comment: can you show `data` output as well ?

Comment: data output sir?? function searchcategory(category_id) is the one i use sir for also outputting the data from the database